# Removing list effect when tapping on ons-button in the right of ons-list-item

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, onsen-ui

I have ons-list as follows:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onItemSelect(item);">
     <ons-row>
          <ons-col width="105px">
              <img ng-src="{{item.thumb}}"></img>
          </ons-col>
          <ons-col>
          <div class="item-title">
              {{ item.name }}
          </div>
          </ons-col>
          <ons-col>
              <ons-button ng-click="onClick();">Add</ons-button>
          </ons-col>
     </ons-row>
 </ons-list-item>
```

There is always an effect after tapping on the list and the same thing goes when tapping on Add button.

I wonder is there any way to remove the effect when tapping on Add button on the right-side of the list?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the effect when tapping on the "Add" button you should use a `modifier` on that button like this:

```
<ons-button modifier="noeffect" ng-click="onClick();">Add</ons-button>
```

and apply your custom CSS for that button:

```
.button--noeffect:active{/*Keep the background color the same on tap*/
    opacity:1;
}
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQRZEo).

If you want to remove the tap effect from your list items and you want only the "Add" button to work on tap then delete only: 
`modifier="tappable"` from your list items.

OnsenUI has some standard [modifiers](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingModifier) that can be applied to buttons and list items, but you can also create your own like above.

Comment: JcDenton86, Appreciated your input. Is it possible to remove tap-effect on ons-list when the Add button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I say in my answer that if you want to remove the tap effect on the list item then remove the `modifier="tappable"` only and leave the rest as is

Comment: See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYvGbN). Changed so list items are not tappable but the button is